# slapd.conf: unknown directive <objectClass:> inside backend database definition

Tags: openldap

I'm pretty new to openLDAP and I am trying to set up a password policy.  I have the following in my slapd.conf:

```
include /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema
moduleload ppolicy.la

objectClass: top
objectClass: device
objectClass: pwdPolicy
cn: default
pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdMaxAge: 5184000
pwdExpireWarning: 432000
pwdInHistory: 6
pwdCheckQuality: 1
pwdMinLength: 8
pwdMaxFailure: 5
pwdLockout: TRUE
pwdLockoutDuration: 1920
pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0
pwdFailureCountInterval: 0
pwdMustChange: TRUE
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
pwdSafeModify: FALSE
pwdCheckModule: check_password.so
pwdCheckQuality: 2
```

the problem though is that when I restart slapd I get the following error:
/etc/openldap/slapd.conf: line 86: unknown directive  inside backend database definition.

can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: So I extracted the config out of the slapd.conf and into its own ldif file and ran the ladapadd command. I am no longer getting the unknown directive error, however I am getting an error saying the pwdCheckModule is not allowed.  Any Ideas????

Comment: one more thing I know in the example above there are two entries for pwdCheckQuality I have corrected that since the initial posting of this.

Comment: I believe my problem is solved. I added objectClass: pwdPolicyChecker to the ldif file and it ran without error.  once I do some testing I will update this thread to let everyone know how it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem here is that you are inventing syntax. LDIF commands don't belong in slapd.conf.